# Python Script in Azure pipelines failing with error

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am trying to execute python script using filePath option, though I am passing the correct path the script task is failing with error **'The given path was not to a file'**, below are the task configuration in yaml & error screen shots, please correct me if I am doing something wrong with the configuration

Thanks
Santosh

[image: task configuration]

[image: Error]

Comment: Sorry, seems it was a typo from my side in the scriptPah, just realized it while posting. This is resolved now.I will close this thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The config seems to be correct, except the typo with **scriptPath**, after correcting it works fine.